# How to add Plugins to a server thats already gone live.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Hello all i have a small ftb server and i have had it up and running for a good month or so and dedicated players, but most would like to see the essentials and other plugins added due to lag issues and other things. So i was wondering if there was a way to get that without damaging their player saved data or the world they have all been building in? if so can someone help with how to do this

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the server, make a backup, install the new plugins, and start it again.

If anything goes wrong, stop the server, restore, and start without the plugin/plugins.